# Algorthim to find best possible coordinate to place an item

Tags: python, algorithm

I am working on a problem but can not quite categorize it.

The problem consist of putting some items on a grid.

Each edge between an item and another item gives a certain benefit and is supposed to be placed such that I get the maximum  possible sum of benefits for the particular configuration of that grid.

The grid itself has some coordinates that can not contain an item.(such as a wall)

It is also allowed not to place some items.

Can I get some guidance on how to go about it?

Algorithm, process of going about the problem, data structure to use or any relevant information.

Unfortunately I can't make the question any clearer.

Thanks

Comment: I feel like this is an NP-type problem...

Comment: Sounds to me like a [`longest path problem`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) in a graph which unfortunately is NP-hard.

Comment: Do the naive version first (go through the grid and test each location / go through each item and test each position), then build out from that - maybe it's fast enough? The description is far too vague to say anything more specific. You can give examples, show the problem, add more details about how the grid is structured, etc.

Comment: @Mushroomator exactly what I'm writing now, but it seems like this may be closed before I can answer...

Comment: *"Each edge between an item and another item gives a certain benefit and is supposed to be placed such that I get the maximum possible sum of benefits for the particular configuration of that grid."* How is the benefit determined? Does it depend only on the pair of items? Or on the location in the grid? Please tell us what the data structure holding the benefits looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my high-level thoughts on this.

So, this is sounding to me like a graph problem. Each item in your "item bank" will become a node in the graph. You then make edges between the nodes, and then assign a weight (integer value) to an edge based on how beneficial the relationship is between the two nodes the edge connects.

Once you've set up the graph, you could then implement a [maximum flow](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/max-flow-problem-introduction/) algorithm. Of course, this would also require that you set up "source" and "sink" nodes. The maximum flow you get would then represent the maximum benefit.

Comment: Perhaps my edit will make it clearer